# Can Jenkins be used for builds in the project or is it a must to use either Maven or ANT for builds?

Tags: maven, jenkins

Can we use directly Jenkins for builds in the project, or is it a must to use either Maven or ANT for it?

As per my understanding this is the process, please correct me if am wrong.
Write the scripts using hybrid framework in Selenium webdriver, configure the tests in testng file, then create a batch file and upload in Jenkins for creating cron jobs.

Now my question is, can we use Jenkins directly for builds, or do we have to use Maven for software builds?

Comment: Please remove selenium tag. Selenium has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: With jenkins you can launch pretty much everything. When you configure a job look at the add build step, you can execute shell scripts, perform http requests... There are also many plugins, especially many selenium plugins.

Comment: While you can launch everything in scripts as indicated in @StephaneM comment, your build tool (Maven, Ant, etc.) have many more build in features that you would just be replicating trying to do it in Jenkins without the tool.

Answer (score 0):

A Jenkins pipeline is not meant to be the build script. You can do a lot in Jenkins pipelines, and could replicate some fairly complex builds with it, but that is not the best way to handle it. Use Jenkins as the glue to piece all of your build/test/deploy scripts together.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be , NO. Even though you can use Jenkins to do a build, (as  you know its just a execution of a program).

The use of Jenkins should be to configure your CI, process (pipeline) where as for builds you should be using a tool like Maven, Ant  (There are any more) (which most of these tools are pretty easy to configure).

In that way the maintainability of your work will be easy. The upgrades will be seamless in the future.